# In UML/ER diagramming, how to notate & make transaction requirements with entity that has different values depending on a certain attribute?

Tags: sql, uml, entity-relationship

I am diagramming an art museum system, where there are `Permanent_Art_Object`s. Each `Permanent_Art_Object` has many attributes, and can also be either a 1) `Sculpture/Statue`, 2)  `Painting`, or 3) `Other`. Depending on whether it's a sculpture/statue, painting, or other, it has sub-attributes unique to itself.

Here is an example of these sub-attributes.

[image]

What is the proper notation for showing these 'sub-attributes'?
For example, if `Permanent_Art_Object` is `Other`, it has as sub-attributes `Type` and `Style`.

Also, how would I make a query to `INSERT INTO Permanent_Art_Object VALUES()` for a new art object, if there's so much variety??

Comment: Hint: use a subclass for each kind of object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on what you are making. If this is purely for a database, I think ERD's are the cleanest way for modeling but a sidenote is that there are atleast 4 types of notations. Below is how I would do it in UML and ERD with the limited context I have.

**More info about ERD's:**

- Basics: http://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/~gurari/course/cse670/cse670Ch2.xht
- Specialisations: http://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/~gurari/course/cse670/cse670Ch16.xht
- Overview of different types: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model#Cardinalities

**My example:**

[image: UML and ERD example]

Comment: Thanks zondvloed, your answer proved to office assistance, even in regards to things I was not originally referring. Cheers.

Comment: You're welcome :-) Click the green V to accept the answer. If you need more help with diagrams, just message me.